# Cleanly infer the type of an array value

Tags: typescript, types, inferred-type

So technically, I have already figured out an answer to this question, but am looking for a cleaner approach. Similarly, I haven't seen any SO questions or documentation specifically laying out how to do this.

First, an example to then build upon: I know that if I have a typed array, I can infer the type of each value in this way:

```
// just with types
type Tuple = [item1: number, item2: string];
type Item1Type = Tuple[0]; // type is number
type Item2Type = Tuple[1]; // type is string

// or with `typeof`
const myTuple: Tuple = [1, 'one'];
type InferredItem1Type = typeof myTuple[0]; // type is number
type InferredItem2Type = typeof myTuple[1]; // type is string
```

If I have a generic like this though and all I have access to is an instance of this type:

```
// the generic type
type GenericObjectWithList<T> = {
  list: T[];
};

// the instance i have access to
const object: GenericObjectWithList<string> = {
  list: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
};
```

I want to infer the type of the inner list.

```
// infer the type of the list
type InferredListType = typeof object['list'][0]; // type is string
```

As you can see, I've already figured out that I can infer this type similar to the approach in my first example, but I'm wondering, is there a cleaner way to infer this type? I would expect there to be a way to infer the single value type of a list without needing to do `[0]`. If there isn't a another way to do this, would someone mind explaining why this approach is the only way we'd *want* this to be the way to infer an array value's type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- List item

Arrays are indexed by a `number`, which means you can drill into an array with `number` in order to get the value types from that array.

`ArrayType[number]` is typically how you would do this. Indexing a non tuple array by zero is pretty much the same thing, but it hints to the programmer that the indexed value would be different for different numbers, which isn't right.

```
type StrArr = string[]
type ArrVal = StrArr[number] // string
```

Or from your code:

```
type InferredListType = typeof object['list'][number]; // type is string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=73&pln=22&pc=1#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)

---

This works with tuples, too.

```
type MyTuple = [123, 'asd']
type TupleVal = MyTuple[number] // 123 | 'asd'
```

But, of course, you lost the information of the position of each type in that tuple. If you need that, that's where you would use `[0]`, `[1]`, etc, instead.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAqBXMAbaBeKBtAjAJgGYAaKAcgEMBnAE1IF0AoUSKJVCANXJSkzjbRYAdogC2AIwgAnOlAD0cqPgJQAPmSq0gA)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR `typeof object['list'][number]`**

Note: I rewrote this answer on 2022-01-19.
You'll want the section "Element of array held in object property".

This is more of a general "wiki" than a specific answer, but it does include what you want.
Alex Wayne's answer is simple and to the point, and a great answer.

### Intro

You can use the *type* (including a union of types) of the index instead of a literal value when indexing types.
This works for any indexable object, and is the basis of practically any advanced TypeScript.

As you already know, you can get the type of a variable using `typeof`.
Similarly, you can use `keyof` to get the type of the keys of an indexable type.
E.g.

```js
type Obj1 = {
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
}

type KeyOfObj1 = keyof Obj1 // = 'key1' | 'key2'

type Obj2 = {
  [key: string]: number
}

type KeyOfObj2 = keyof Obj2 // = string
```

I will go through some examples of this step by step, getting progressively more advanced.

**Important note**: `typeof obj['key']` can be used instead of `(typeof obj)['key']`, but it can get confusing in more complex constructions. Also, `keyof typeof obj` is equivalent to `keyof (typeof obj)` and `keyof (typeof obj)['key']` is equivalent to `keyof ((typeof obj)['key'])`.

And of course, these are just "atoms" of this sort of thing. *You can combine all of these in infinitely many ways.* And by using generic types, you can create reusable "functions" that do what you need, instead of writing it all out every time.

For a good "course" to learn more, I recommend the docs (especially [Creating Types from Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html)) and [Advanced TypeScript on Execute Program](https://www.executeprogram.com/courses/advanced-typescript).

From the linked docs section, "Creating Types from Types":

> TypeScript’s type system is very powerful because it allows expressing types in terms of other types.
>
> The simplest form of this idea is generics, we actually have a wide variety of type operators available to use. It’s also possible to express types in terms of values that we already have.
>
> By combining various type operators, we can express complex operations and values in a succinct, maintainable way. In this section we’ll cover ways to express a new type in terms of an existing type or value.
>
> - Generics - Types which take parameters
> - Keyof Type Operator - Using the keyof operator to create new types
> - Typeof Type Operator - Using the typeof operator to create new types
> - Indexed Access Types - Using Type['a'] syntax to access a subset of a type
> - Conditional Types - Types which act like if statements in the type system
> - Mapped Types - Creating types by mapping each property in an existing type
> - Template Literal Types - Mapped types which change properties via template literal strings

As you can see, I am only scratching the surface here. Onwards!

### Keys of object

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 123,
  key2: 'abc'
}

type KeysOfObj = keyof typeof obj // = 'key1' | 'key2'
```

### Property of object

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 123,
  key2: 'abc'
}

type Key1 = (typeof obj)['key1'] // = number
```

### All properties of object

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 123,
  key2: 'abc'
}

// Concise
type PropertiesOfObj = (typeof obj)[keyof typeof obj] // = number | string

// Verbose
type TypeOfObj = typeof obj // = { key1: number, key2: string }
type KeysOfObj = keyof TypeOfObj // = 'key1' | 'key2'
type PropertiesOfObj = TypeOfObj[KeysOfObj]
// = { key1: number, key2: string }['key1' | 'key2']
// = number | string
```

### Array element / All array elements

```js
// Union of all elements:
const arr = [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
type ElementOfArr = (typeof arr)[number] // = number | string

// Specific element/index:
type Element2OfArr = (typeof arr)[2] // = string
```

### Element of nested array

Same rules as above apply in relation to the array.

```js
const obj = {
  arr: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
};

// Concise
type ElementOfArr = (typeof obj)['arr'][number]; // = string

// Verbose
type Arr = (typeof obj)['arr'] // = string[]
type ElementOfArr = Arr[number] // = string
```

### Property of nested object

```js
const obj = {
  key1: {
    nested1: 123,
    nested2: 'abc'
  }
}

// Concise but dreadful
type Nested1 = (typeof obj)['key1'][keyof (typeof obj)['key1']] // = number | string

// Goldilocks (although, you could do the `typeof obj` separately).
type Key1 = (typeof obj)['key1'] // = { nested1: number, nested2: string }
type Nested1 = Key1[keyof Key1] // = number | string
```

Comment: Rewrote this almost entirely today (2022-01-19). You may want to reread it if you still are interested in advanced types. I highly recommend that linked section of the docs.